# How to connect to Cisco Show and Share API from Java app

Tags: java, rest, firefox, firefox-addon, httpurlconnection

I can connect to the API via Firefox's `RESTClient`, but not through my java app.

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
```

Also, `url = https://<myCompany:myPort>/vportal/services/xml/api`

All of the variables match what I'm using in `RESTClient`, but I keep getting `HTTP error code: 500`

Does anyone see why I may not be able to connect?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a firewall blocking my connection between VM and cloud server.  I was connecting to the APY via Firefox on my local machine and using the app on a VM.